# HTML for displaying Azure Blobs in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to create an upload tool where a user can upload and view their files in ASP.NET MVC written in C#.

So far, I am able to get the user to upload their files, but I cannot figure out the HTML for the relevant View (MyFiles.cshtml) so that the user can see the names of the files that they have uploaded.

Here is the code for my controller:

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult MyFiles()
    {           
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");

        List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
        foreach (var blobItem in blobContainer.ListBlobs())
        {
            blobs.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());
        }
        return View(blobs);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyFiles(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureString"));

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");

            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(image.FileName);
            blob.UploadFromStream(image.InputStream);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("MyFiles");
    }
}
```

All I want the View to do is show the name of the file, not the whole path including the URL to the storage account and container.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the Name property instead of the Uri property ?

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.name.aspx

Hope this helps